# Python xml.etree.ElementTree explanation

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I've got a question that's been haunting me a little, due to the lack of information I've been able to receive from peers.

In regards to importing and parsing XMLs into Python, are the different elements associated with the XML stored in memory? To put it another way, are the elements received by specific commands actually elements set to memory address?

EX.

`[<Element 'Property' at 0x18f17a390>]`

```
 ^          ^            ^
 |          |            |
```

Element   ||    Tag    ||   Memory Address(?)

If I'm wrong, what would the portion at the end be called?

*EDIT*:

I've have been reading from here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: What you're showing is the string representation of an object. So, `Element` is the class of the object (specifically `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`), `Property` is the tag of the node used to create the object, and `0x18f17a390` is the location of the object in memory. Yes, objects are created in memory for each node in the XML file.

Comment: Cheers Jared! Darn, I wish you would've just thrown that up as an answer.  I've been working with them for about two months, smoothly and efficiently, but that was just making me feel real insecure.